# Magento Admin Custom Tab in Catalog Product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom tab under catalog product, the tab is coming fine but when i click on the tab the template for the block is not loading. It echo what i type but it is not fetching the template. I write this function in a class HTC_Csvpricing_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    echo "I m here";
    $this->setTemplate('csvpricing/tab.phtml');
}
```

Here what I write in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/csvpricing.xml

```
<csvpricing_adminhtml_csvpricing_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="csvpricing/adminhtml_csvpricing" name="csvpricing" />
    </reference>
</csvpricing_adminhtml_csvpricing_index>

<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>csvpricing_tab</name>
            <block>csvpricing/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

Please guide what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: Also when i inspect the element i get this message there "This tab contains invalid data. Please solve the problem before saving."

Comment: Could you show us your template file ?

Comment: @dagfr in template file i just have [code]<?php echo "Test" ?>

Comment: @dagfr can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow : 
Module config.xml

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <your_module>
                    <file>your-module.xml</file>
                </your_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create the layout XML in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your-module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>your_module_some_tab</name>
                <block>your_module/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

Create the tab block in {your_module}/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tab.php:

```
class Your_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
    /**
     * Set the template for the block
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/tab/some-tab.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the label used for the tab relating to this block
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Some Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the title used by this tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Some Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether to display the tab
     * Add logic here to decide whether you want the tab to display
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the tab being hidden
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you need to create a data helper to support translation, if your module does not have one already.

Make the tabs template in /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/some-tab.phtml:

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4>Some Heading</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
        <div class="hor-scroll">
            <!-- your content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and it just show me the tab as in my case but its not loading the tab data when clicked :(

Comment: check the error logs there is must be something you type wrong in the XML or something ?

Comment: can u check the system/exception logs and see if there is errors also show the structure you built !!

Comment: I checked the system/exception logs and there is no error. The thing is if I am doing wrong in the xml or Tab.php the tab would not come but tab is coming fine instead it is not fething tab data only.

Comment: yes because the block/type or phtml is incorrect so it doesn't fill the data !

Comment: I used it on my local system and all is working fine but on the client server i am facing this issue.

Comment: so this is not issue related to the code !! check logs or debug the code see whats happening !!